SpringSecurity6 - implement AuthorizationManager with MetadataSource
Thanks for reading.
springsecurity5.x  : config
`
@Bean
public FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor() throws Exception {
    FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor = new FilterSecurityInterceptor();
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    filterSecurityInterceptor
          .setSecurityMetadataSource(filterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource());
    filterSecurityInterceptor.setAccessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager());
    return filterSecurityInterceptor; 
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Bean
public FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource filterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource() {
    return new MyFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(urlAndRoleResourcesMapLoader());
}

@Bean
public UrlAndRoleResourcesMapLoader urlAndRoleResourcesMapLoader() {
    return new UrlAndRoleResourcesMapLoader(); // load url-role data from database
}

@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> voters = new ArrayList<>();
    RoleVoter roleVoter = new RoleVoter();
    roleVoter.setRolePrefix("");
    voters.add(roleVoter);
    AffirmativeBased affirmativeBased = new AffirmativeBased(voters);
    return affirmativeBased;
} 

`
SpringSecurity6.2.x  : How do I set it up?
SpringSecurity6.2.3 Authorization

NOTE: AccessDecisionVoter was marked as deprecated starting with 5.8.x of Spring Security. It is recommended to use AuthorizationManager instead.
